# Log in and check the account type

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

hi am new here and new in C#.
i want to make a simple desktop app that include a login (simple and done already)
but i'm confused in how can i make a different main window by account type that needs to be checked in the database (i have Users and one SuperUser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you make a two seperated windows one for users and one for the superuser OR (*if there is not too much differents between these two windows*), you just have to decide based on the users table what to show something as simple as this:

```
if (this.UserType == 1) { //u assign UserType variable based on users table row
 var superForm = new SuperForm(); //in case of use 2 seperated forms
 superForm.Show();
}
```

OR assuming for example the superuser window just have another button it will
still be as simple as this too:

```
public MainForm(int userType) { // u pass userType when creating the form after the login
    if (userType == 1) { 
        this.superButton.Visible = true; //by default superButton would be hidden
    }
}
```

And for the mysql structure you just make a `UserType` field in the `UsersTable` that holds for example value **1** for the Superuser and **0** for the other users.